# Android How to load Image into CircleImageView from Device - NavigationDrawer?

Tags: android, image, layout, navigation, drawer

I have no idea how to load image from device into CircleImageView. There are my code of ***nav_header_main.xml***:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/background_material_red"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profile_image"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:src="@drawable/background_material_red"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:onClick="chooseImage" />

   <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/userName"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:textColor="#FFF"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:gravity="start"
       android:paddingBottom="4dp"
       android:id="@+id/userName"
       app:typeface="roboto_medium"
       android:layout_below="@+id/profile_image"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/profile_image"
       android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

    <com.devspark.robototextview.widget.RobotoTextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/userEmail"
        android:id="@+id/userEmail"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        app:typeface="roboto_regular"
        android:layout_below="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/userName"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and ***MainActivity*** code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NavigationView navigationView = null;
    private Toolbar toolbar = null;
    private MainFragment mainFragment;
    private GalleryFragment galleryFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainFragment = new MainFragment();
        galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        if (drawer != null) {
            drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        }
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        if (navigationView != null) {
            navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer != null) {
            if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
                drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            } else {
                super.onBackPressed();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_main) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, mainFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_health) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, galleryFragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I will repeat my question: how can I, programmatically, load image from device to the profile_image which is in the ***nav_header_main.xml*** file

Answer (score 0):

This is a example. Try it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/20/select-an-image-from-gallery-in-android-and-show-it-in-an-imageview/

http://tjkannan.blogspot.in/2012/01/load-image-from-camera-or-gallery.html